# sql aggregate with no aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tyring to insert Column called `SummonerName` from `Summoner` Table to `Order` Table.

It is giving me error saying that `SummonerName` is non aggregate.

I want this to show like from:

```
SummonerID OCC
94         5
1          4
```

to:

```
SummonerName SummonerID OCC
Paul         94         5
George       1          4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT s.SummonerName, o.SummonerID, COUNT(o.SummonerID) AS 'OCC'    
FROM Orders AS o    
JOIN Summoner AS s    
    ON o.SummonerID = s.SummonerID    
GROUP BY o.SummonerID    
ORDER BY OCC;
```

Comment: Add s.SummonerName to the GROUP BY  clause.

Comment: Thank you!! That was way more simple than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either group by all the non-aggregates you're selecting:

```
SELECT s.SummonerName, o.SummonerID, COUNT(o.SummonerID) AS 'OCC'    
FROM Orders AS o    
JOIN Summoner AS s    
    ON o.SummonerID = s.SummonerID    
GROUP BY o.SummonerID, s.SummonerName 
ORDER BY OCC;
```

Or add a windowed function and remove your `group by`:

```
SELECT s.SummonerName, o.SummonerID, COUNT(o.SummonerID) over (partition by o.SummonerID)  AS 'OCC' 
FROM Orders AS o    
JOIN Summoner AS s    
    ON o.SummonerID = s.SummonerID    
ORDER BY OCC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because with SQL, EVERY column being selected that is not listed in the GROUP BY must have an aggregate function applied to it.  Some SQL server, like MySQL, do not enforce this and silently pick a value.  You should either add SummonerName to the GROUP BY, or add an aggregate function, like MIN or MAX, to SummonerName column in SELECT field list.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you are using `GROUP BY o.summonerID`, your new summoner name column has to either be the result of a calculation (like MIN or MAX) or be in the GROUP BY clause.

Adding o.SummonerName to the GROUP by clause will probably get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT s.SummonerName, o.SummonerID, COUNT(o.SummonerID) AS 'OCC'    
  FROM Orders AS o    
  JOIN Summoner AS s ON o.SummonerID = s.SummonerID    
  GROUP BY s.SummonerName, o.SummonerID    
  ORDER BY OCC;
```

If you can't do that for some reason, you can make the calculation a sub-select, like this:

```
SELECT s.SummonerName, s.SummonerID, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders where SummonerID = s.SummonerID) AS 'OCC'    
  FROM Orders AS o     
  ORDER BY OCC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add s.SummonerName to the GROUP BY clause:

GROUP BY o.SummonerID, s.SummonerName